# How to display an Excel sheet in Django?

Tags: python, django, excel

im working on a Django website and i wnat to display an Excel Sheet that can later be edited on the website. Right now i am only able to upload a file but nothing is displayed. I know FileField is probably the way to go but how do i make the file show on the webpage? Django-excel seems does not do the job for me, because i think there is a much easier way to just display a file (but not an image).

Here is my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/")
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is my `views.py`

```
    class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()



def index(request):
    documents = Document
    template = loader.get_template('documents/index.html')
    context = {
        'documents' : documents
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))



def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('documents:index')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'documents/model_form_upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

My `forms.py`

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('description', 'document')
```

and `my upload_template.html` where the file should be displayed at the end

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>



<p><a href="{% url 'documents:index' %}">Return to Home</a></p>
```

I think i'll just have to change something in the views.py but i ran out of ideas. Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: A quick way would be to read the file in using `pandas.read_excel` and then use `pandas.DataFrame.to_html`. You can drop the resulting html straight into a template as long as you mark it as `safe`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. Is there any way to change, delete, add rows in the sheet by clicking into the textfields, just like in Excel?